# Update custom property from Kivy binding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to be able to update the custom widget class property whenever I passed the value to Kivy. I am not sure if this is the same as binding. I have read about Event Dispatcher and the on but I was not able to get it to work.

For example, given the code below I would like to pass in `chart_type: 'barh'` in Kivy and whenever I run the program it should show a horizontal bar.

However, my brain does not seem to understand how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
from kivy.properties import (
    ListProperty,
    StringProperty,
)

kv = """
BoxLayout:
    MDBarChart:
        id: bar
        chart_type: 'barh' # Not working
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "Update"
        # on_press: app.mdchart.update()
"""


class MDBarChart(FigureCanvasKivyAgg, EventDispatcher):

    x_nums = ListProperty([1, 2, 3])
    y_nums = ListProperty([2, 5, 7])
    label_x = StringProperty('x')
    label_y = StringProperty('y')

    # Be able to change this in kivy lang and reflect on Kivy
    chart_type = StringProperty('bar')


    def on_chart_type(self, instance, value):
        self.chart_type = self.chart_type


    def update(self):
        blue_dot = mlines.Line2D(range(1), range(1), marker='o', color='#6200EA',
                                 markersize=15, label='Purple Dot', linewidth=0)

        x = self.x_nums
        y = self.y_nums

        if self.chart_type == "bar":
            plt.bar(x, y, label='Bars1', color='#6200EA')
        elif self.chart_type == "barh":
            plt.barh(x, y, label='Bars1', color='#6200EA')
        elif self.chart_type == "line":
            plt.plot(x, y, label='Bars1', color='#6200EA')
        elif self.chart_type == "stackplot":
            plt.stackplot(x, y, color=['#6200EA','#D1C4E9', '#5E35B1'])

        plt.xlabel(self.label_x)
        plt.ylabel(self.label_y)
        plt.legend(handles=[blue_dot], loc='upper right', prop={'size': 14})

    def remove_borders(self):
        for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
            spine.set_visible(False)

        plt.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MDBarChart, self).__init__(plt.gcf(), **kwargs)
        self.update()


class ProgressApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ProgressApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess waking up at 4:30 in the morning and drinking loads of caffeine makes my brain think better.

I updated my **init** method to look as below:

```
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MDBarChart, self).__init__(plt.gcf(), **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args:self.update())
```

By updating that now I can update the KV Lang file and the changes reflect on the GUI.